# Quickest/shortest way of writing contents of dictionary to XML using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

```
string PrintDict(Dictionary<string, string> MyDict)
{
    XElement p = new XElement("DictionaryContents");
    MyDict.ForEach(kvp => p.Add(new XElement(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
    return p.ToString();
}
```

Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the way you're approaching the problem: don't write the dictionary to an XElement, but try to construct an XElement from a dictionary. LINQ-to-XML makes this particularly easy.

```
var xml = new XElement("DictionaryContents",
    myDict.Select(kvp => new XElement(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));

return xml.ToString();
```